# How to Enforce FTP Disablement on Newly Created App Service/Function Apps in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ftp, azure-web-app-service, policy

Is there a way to enforce that newly created App Services and Function Apps will have the FTP disabled in Azure? I am aware that I can turn off the FTP manually by changing the configuration in the Azure Portal but is there a way to do it automatically/programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable both FTP and FTPS if you don't use FTP deployment by using ***Azure CLI*** and ***Azure Powershell***.

- Possible values for `--ftps-state` are `AllAllowed` (FTP and FTPS enabled), `Disabled` (FTP and FTPs disabled), and `FtpsOnly` (FTPS only).

***Azure CLI***

- Run the [az webapp config set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment#az_webapp_deployment_list_publishing_profiles) command with the `--ftps-state` argument.

```cs
az webapp config set --name <app-name> --resource-group <group-name> --ftps-state Disabled
```

***Azure Powershell***

- Run the [Set-AzWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azwebapp) command with the `-FtpsState` parameter.

```cs
Set-AzWebApp -Name <app-name> -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -FtpsState Disabled
```

- Go to Azure Portal and check for the ***Disabled FTP option.***